# Flink+Kafka reset checkpoint and offset

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In short, I'd like to re-run a Flink pipeline on data in Kafka **from the beginning**.

Flink 0.10.2, Kafka 0.8.2.

I have a tweets topic in Kafka with retention 2 hours, and a pipeline in Flink that counts tweets with a sliding window of 5 minutes every 10s.

If I interrupt the pipeline and I re-run it, I'd like it to re-read older tweets, thus emitting the count of 5 min worth of tweets.
Instead, it seems to restart from newly arrived tweets, so it takes 5 minutes before the count is "at regime".

I've tried both `auto.offset.reset = smallest/earliest`, and changing the `group.id`, but unsuccessfully. I also tried to manually change offsets in Kafka as described here: https://metabroadcast.com/blog/resetting-kafka-offsets

I then assume that the issue can be related to Flink's checkpointing, but I have no clue/can't find information on how to reset that.

Can anyone share some working code? Thanks, E.

Comment: I guess you need to use savepoints. Those will be available in the upcoming 1.0 release (or you might want to check out the current master): https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/savepoints.html

Comment: That would be even nicer, but I'd also be ok on re-reading everything from Kafka from the beginning and recomputing whatever is the last window.

Answer (score 2):

To re-read everything available in a Kafka topic, setting a new "group.id" and the "auto.offset.reset" to "earliest" should be sufficient.

If that doesn't work, there's something wrong.

Comment: That's what I thought, but Flink seems more complex as it manages an internal state AND "pushes a copy of that" to zookeeper.

Comment: What Flink does is the following: It indeed keeps and internal state of the last read offsets internally. If the Flink job fails for some reason, it restores from that state.
This allows users to perform downstream operations with exactly-once semantics.
Flink uses a distributed snapshot mechanism, to backup the state periodically. Once a distributed snapshot has been confirmed by all operators, the Kafka source "commits" the offsets into ZK as well.
This way, users can restart the job from the offset in ZK. Note that the mechanism from ZK doesn't give exactly-once guarantees.

Comment: thanks for the details - do you know if is there a way to override Flink's state? (or similarly to force using ZK offset?)

Comment: The state is discarded when a job is stopping or cancelled. There is no way to change values in the state or to manually delete it.
But you can just cancel and start the job and it'll get the offset from ZK (as long as the group.id is the same and the offset is still available in kafka)